# Como transformar um dado de hora 01:30 em minutos 90 no R

Tags: r

Tenho uma coluna com dados de horas, gostaria de transformar essas horas em minutos.

```
T.Real <- c("08:42","08:33","00:41","01:11","01:35","00:45","01:43","01:03","01:06")
```

Comment: Multiplica as hora por 60 e soma com os minutos

Comment: Sua pergunta não foi muito bem construída. Da próxima vez, coloque o código do que você já tentou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando o seguinte vetor como exemplo

```
horas <- c("1:00:00", "0:45:00", "0:30:00", "1:30:00")
```

Seguem duas opções:

- utilizando o pacote `chron`

  ```
  library(chron)
  ch <- times(horas)
  60 * hours(ch) + minutes(ch)
  ```
- utilizando o pacote `lubridate`

  ```
  library(lubridate)
  res <- hms(horas)
  hour(res)*60 + minute(res)
  ```

As funções `times` e `hms` transformam o objeto `horas` em um formato de tempo.

Para adicionar esses valores como uma nova variável do seu banco de dados, você pode:

- utilizando `base R`

  ```
  novo.GT.Real <- as.character(tempodesolo$GT.Real) 
  res <- hm(novo.GT.Real) 
  tempodesolo$novo.GT.Real <- hour(res)*60 + minute(res)
  ```
- utlizando o pacote `dplyr` - vou exemplificar com vários `mutate` para você entender o passo a passo. Você poderia colocar tudo dentro de um único `mutate`

  ```
  tempodesolo <- tempodesolo  %>%
    mutate(novo.GT.Real = as.character(GT.Real))  %>%
    mutate(novo.GT.Real = hm(novo.GT.Real))  %>%
    mutate(novo.GT.Real = hour(novo.GT.Real)*60 + minute(novo.GT.Real))
  ```